# How to get 4K @ 60Hz with GTX 970 and HDMI 2.0

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, 4k-resolution

I used to be able to have my PC running 4K @ 60Hz with HDMI 2.0

But somehow, that option is gone. I can't enable 60Hz anymore, the customize button on the NVidia control panel is just greyed out.

Any idea?

Specs:

> Monitor: 32-inch 4K Qnix with HDMI 2.0
>
> GFX: GTX 970
>
> Windows 10 64-bit
>
> Nvidia driver

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled DSR (Dynamic Super Resolution)? This disables custom resolutions because it adds its own settings.

Comment: Just retest and looks only the HDMI1 port on my monitor support 2.0. Other ports (HDMI2, HDMI3) supportonly 1.4.

Comment: Yeah, that's also very typical for 4K monitors.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I plugged in the wrong port on my monitor: HDMI 1.4. You have to use HDMI 2.0 port to get 4K @ 60Hz. It's not clearly labeled on the monitor which HDMI port is 1.4 and which one is 2.0, I found out after some trials and errors.